# Unity Editor right-click key disabled

Tags: unity-game-engine, keyboard-shortcuts, contextmenu

In Unity 2017.3.0f3, I've noticed that a few Windows shortcuts have been disabled.

Namely the most useful, right-click key (aka the menu key) and alt shortcuts to access menus.

Is there any workaround? I find being able to mostly rely on the keyboard gives a much faster workflow than having to constantly switch between mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Though `right-click key` would of course be the mouse ^^

Comment: @derHugo I meant the menu key sorry. The one that triggers/simulate a right click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click should work e.g. in the Asset folder view for creating and editing Assets and folders. I don't know where else that would be necessary.

---

By default there should actually be shortcuts with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> for some menus like `File`, `Edit`, `Window` and `Help`.

On creating your own [menu items](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html) you can also define custom shortcuts for them:

> To create a hotkey you can use the following special characters: % (ctrl on Windows, cmd on macOS), # (shift), & (alt). If no special modifier key combinations are required the key can be given after an underscore. For example to create a menu with hotkey shift-alt-g use "MyMenu/Do Something #&g". To create a menu with hotkey g and no key modifiers pressed use "MyMenu/Do Something _g".
>
> Some special keyboard keys are supported as hotkeys, for example "#LEFT" would map to shift-left. The keys supported like this are: LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, F1 .. F12, HOME, END, PGUP, PGDN.
>
> A hotkey text must be preceded with a space character ("MyMenu/Do_g" won't be interpreted as hotkey, while "MyMenu/Do _g" will).

Comment: Right click works, but not the keyboard key shortcut. As the Alt+Letter they don't work for me. I know I can create my own shortcuts and maybe could "hack" something but that feels like monkey patching.

Comment: I didn't realize the `alt + A` (and others) actually contained the stuff I was looking for and act as though I did hit the Menu key. Thank you!

Comment: @derHugo I realised that you edited some answers from my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089098/how-to-clone-several-game-objects-in-a-way-that-clone-properties-of-one-can-be-a?noredirect=1&lq=1). I've added comments with some info.